# Which machine learning algorithms are more suitable for binary classification?

Tags: classification, binary-classification

We know that there are many different types of classification algorithms. But among the different categories of classification algorithms, which algorithms are suitable for binary classification and which are suitable for more classes, and why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to be highly literal, logistic regression is excellent for binary classes but completely inappropriate for $3+$ classes. No worries: there is multinomial logistic regression, the theory of which mimics binary logistic regression (one might consider logistic regression to be a special case of multinomial logistic regression). Depending on the sophistication of my audience, I might be comfortable referring to "logistic regression" and leaving it to them to realize that I mean "multinomial" logistic regression when there are $3+$ categories and "binary" logistic regression when there are $2$ categories.

Random forest can do the binary case but also the multiclass case. Ditto for k-nearest neighbors, support vector machines, and neural networks.

I cannot think of a model for binary classes that lacks a multiclass analogue.

Comment: and why they are suitable (mathematically)?

Comment: @AMZ What would constitute mathematical suitability?

Comment: I think SVMs can per se only do binary classification, since it works with a single separating hyperplane. If you want a multiclass SVM, you need to split the multiclass problem into multiple binary decisions (e.g. with one-vs-one or one-vs-all strategies). 
One could pursue the same approach with logistic regression (loosing inference statistics in the process).

Comment: @AEF Not quite, SVM calculates the margin, and each point has a distance to the margin,  and the model then uses this to decide which side of the margin the point will end up, so there is still not quite a hard classification.

Comment: @user2974951 yes, thats true, but the question and answer are about binary und multiclass problems and not about the difference between hard and soft classification.

Comment: Re your last sentence: any multiclass model is trivially a binary one. And you can always run a binary model $n$ times in a "one class against all others" mode and average the classifications in some suitably smart way. So there is really no hard differentiation. (Things become more interesting if the multiclass case contains *ordered* classes, but even then you can run the binary classifier with "class X or smaller against all higher classes" mode.)

Comment: There is a proper multiclass extension of the SVM (not just one-vs-one and one-vs-all reduction to multiple binary SVMs), the "Crammer-Singer multiclass SVM".

Comment: I wouldn't call neural networks a machine learning algorithm. I tend to see machine learning algorithms as algorithms with firm mathematical description and background. Neural networks are more or less black boxes (except ANFIS and similar). I would classify them in a separate category called deep learning. To expand it further, counting in the amount of data you have and the mathematical rigour of algorithms, I would separate algorithms to: common statistics, machine learning and deep learning.

Comment: @dosvarog A neural network is a regression equation, such as: $$Y = b_{2,1} + w_{2,1}\text{ReLU}(b_{1,1} + w_{1,1}X) + b_{2,2}\text{ReLU}(b_{1,2} + w_{1,2}X)$$ In what way is that not a firm mathematical description?

Comment: @Dave I am not disputing that. Backpropagation is also a firm mathematical description, as gradient descent is. I am saying that in the case of neural networks we don't know anything about parameters and why the network chose exactly those parameters. Or what do they mean, for that matter. For all we know, you could divide every second weight with \sqrt{2} and model would generalize better, or maybe even learn faster. With SVM or k-NN you know exactly what happens, as with logistic expression (loss function is convex, and learned parameters will always be same). That is what I had in mind.

Comment: @Dave And even if you don't agree with me on that matter, we still have the amount of data as argument. If you have small amount of data, you can get away with common statistics. If you have decent amount of data, machine learning. If you have huge amount of multidimensional data, you use neural networks, that is, deep learning. Because machine learning algorithms from a certain point will not work better with additional amount of data. I think that is a good argument to not call neural networks a machine learning algorithm, but too classify them as separate area - deep learning.

Comment: @StephanKolassa yes, of course you can use any multiclass model trivially as binary model. But I thought that SVMs can only do binary decisions, and the only option for multiclass SVM would be to train mutliple binary ones. Thanks to the comment of isarandi, I know better now :)

Comment: Thank you @isarandi for pointing me to the multiclass extension I did not know before!

Answer (score 2):

The answer is that there is no one answer.  The choice of machine learning algorithms - whether for binary or multi-class classification - very much depends upon your data and your application:

- how big is your training set?
- how balanced is the training set?
- how many dependent variables does it contain?
- what is the separability of your two classes on those variables?
- what kind of accuracy/recall do you need?
- Is the result driving life or death decisions, or helping you decide
  what to eat for afternoon snack?
- Are you doing this once, or will you be developing multiple models?

For example, if you have a simple, linearly separable problem with a small training set, then a linear discriminant solution (Fisher) makes the most sense, but if you have a complex separability boundary with a small training data, then LR, SVMs or decision trees may be better, or if you have a large amount of data you can use neural nets.  You should also consider how much time you want to invest in the model.  Generally neural nets are a fairly big investment in time, but simpler models, such as LR and KNN can be implemented in Excel.

That said, more information on the data and the application might allow us to provide better suggestions.